# Cloud Custodian filter GCP compute instances that have a label for datetime that's past

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudcustodian

I want to have a *cloud custodian policy* that marks compute instances for op if they have a label `expires-on` and it's set to a `date/time` that's past the time of evaluation.

I tried looking through the cloud custodian documentation but I'm struggling to find anything about "label filtering" for GCP instances

Do you know about any documentation that could help me better understand label filtering?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cloudcustodian but Labels in gcp can also be used as [State labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#common-uses) and you will be able to [filter it using different options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#filter).

Answer (score 1):

For filtering based on a label, you need to use filter type "value" and as a key, you need to use JSON path:

```
policies:
  - name: my-first-policy
    resource: gcp.instance
    filters:
      - type: value
        key: labels.labelkey
        value: labelvalue
```

where VM instance has label `labelkey: labelvalue`

More details you can find here: https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/filters.html

Comment: How would I specify the value to be “right now” rather than a static number or word?